# Xamarin Android App Crashes when upgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite nuget from 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Xamarin Android app crashes with error

> The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Query.Expression
>   Translators.Internal.SqliteCompositeMethodCallTranslator' threw an
>   exception

when upgrading `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlit`e package from from  2.1 to 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tthe Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite assembly is not linker friendly.(my app had linking enabled via Link "SDK Assemblies Only" to reduce apk sizes)

The code that is failing is a part of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite here and seems to be looking for methods of the DateTime class...

You can add `LinkDescription.xml` file containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<linker>
        <assembly fullname="mscorlib">
                <type fullname="System.DateTime" preserve="methods" />
        </assembly>
</linker>
```

and set its build action to `LinkDescription`

from
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2620#issuecomment-456447322